# Passing value to one Page Object from Another Page Object

Tags: ruby, cucumber, pageobjects, page-object-gem

Using ruby and cheezy page-object gem (along with cucumber).

I have a `page_section` (section B) who's elements will vary based off the value of another `page_section` (section A). I can access each `page_section` fine but I'm trying to pass the value from section B to section A and I can't seem to make it work. I have a variable in section B (not sure of any better way to do it) that I initialize to the value of a span from section A. This doesn't work and gives a `NoMethodError`. Can anyone help me with what I'm trying to do here? I know the title says Page Objects (and technically they are page objects) but I'm going to be using them as `page_sections` of the same root page.

Section B code

```
class SectionB
  include PageObject

  coverage = on(SectionA).coverage_value

  def element_method

    element('element', id: coverage)
  end

 end
```

Section A code

```
class SectionA
  include PageObject

  def coverage_value
    span_element(id: 'coverage-id')
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current approach will determine the `coverage` when the class is compiled. I think you want to determine the value when the object is initialized.

I would initialize a SectionA instance within SectionB:

```
class SectionB
  include PageObject

  def coverage
    SectionA.new(root.browser).coverage_value
  end

  def element_method
    element('element', id: coverage)
  end
end
```